# Nested input and select box with hover transition

Tags: css, select, input, sass, transition

I have a select box that sits directly next to an input box, (see relevant snippet below).

Currently, two seperate transition animations play in order to display both boxes on hover.

I would like to only use a single transition to display both boxes on hover. 
Is there a cleaner way to do this? Could different positioning properties help me? Thanks in advance!

```css
html, body {
  background-color: rgba(64, 124, 165, 1);
}

.quick-search-container {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 350px;
  vertical-align: top;
  white-space: nowrap;
  position: relative;
  top: -5px;
  float: left;
}

.quick-search-container input#search {
  width: 20px;
  height: 30px;
  background: rgba(64, 124, 165, 1); /*replacement*/
  border: none;
  font-size: 10pt;
  float: right;
  color: #262626;
  padding-right: 35px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  color: #000;
  -webkit-transition: width .55s ease, background-color .55s ease;
  -moz-transition: width .55s ease, background-color .55s ease;
  -ms-transition: width .55s ease, background-color .55s ease;
  -o-transition: width .55s ease, background-color .55s ease;
  transition: width .55s ease, background-color .55s ease;
}

.quick-search-container input#search {
  color: #65737e;
  border: none;
}

.quick-search-container .icon {
  position: absolute;
  vertical-align: text-top;
  right: 0;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-top: 6px;
  color: #333;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.quick-search-container .selector {
  float: right;
  vertical-align: text-top;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-top: 6px;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.quick-search-container input#search:focus,
.quick-search-container input#search:active,
select#selector:active {
  outline: none;
}

.quick-search-container:hover input#search {
  outline: none;
  width: 180px;
  background: #fff;
}

.quick-search-container:hover select#selector {
  outline: none;
  width: 100px;
}

.quick-search-container:hover .icon {
  color: rgba(64, 124, 165, 1); /*replacement*/
}

.quick-search-container .selector {
  margin-right: 0px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  transition: width .22s ease, background-color .55s ease;
}

.quick-search-selector {
  margin-right: 0px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  border: none;
  height: 30px;
  width: 0px;
  color: black;
  transition: width .55s ease, background-color .55s ease;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <a class="quick-search-container">
            <span class="icon">
              <i (click)="initQuickSearch()" class="fa fa-search"></i>
            </span>
            <input type="search" id="search" placeholder="Search...">
            <span class="selector">
              <select class="quick-search-selector" id="selector">
                <option>VIN</option>
                <option>Make</option>
                <option>Model</option>
                <option>Cow</option>
              </select>
            </span>
          </a>
```

Comment: Just wrap input and select boxes into a container and set animations on it.

Comment: Could i get an example? How would I manipulate the width of the select and input boxes so they are able to do this? From what I've tried, this does not work.

Comment: It will be a slide animation, use percentage width on the boxes if you need to animate width.

Comment: I'm using SCSS not CSS, CSS was used in the title for scope. @MrLister, editing to reflect that...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just wrap input and select boxes into a container and set animations on it, see the simplified demo by using flexbox below. You can adjust the style as needed.

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g296erLp/)**

```css
html {
  background-color: rgba(64, 124, 165, 1);
}
.quick-search-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 250px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid;
}
.input-select {
  width: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: width 1s;
  display: flex;
}
.quick-search-selector {
  width: 30%;
  height: 30px;
}
.quick-search-input {
  width: 70%;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  outline: 0;
  height: 30px;
}
.quick-search-container:hover .input-select {
  width: 100%;
}
.quick-search-button {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  font-size: 16px;
  background: none;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<a class="quick-search-container">
  <span class="input-select">
    <select class="quick-search-selector" id="selector">
      <option>VIN</option>
      <option>Make</option>
      <option>Model</option>
      <option>Cow</option>
    </select>
    <input type="search" class="quick-search-input" placeholder="Search..." id="search">
  </span>
  <button class="quick-search-button">
    <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
  </button>
</a>
```